# Edit page redirect false gives empty page

Tags: admin-on-rest

```
<Edit title={"XYZ"} {...props}>
<TabbedForm defaultValue={defaultValues} redirect={false}>
```

In the above code I am trying to stop the default behavior of redirection into the List page from Edit page, when click on save button.

The page is not redirected but it displays the empty fields. Once If I click on refresh button, then I can able to see the updated values in the fields.

Comment: Have you tried `redirect="edit"` ?

Comment: I just tried with `redirect={false}` on the demo app and it works as expected. Can you create a repository showcasing your problem ?